# CodeDeploy fails with the message "Validation of PKCS7 signed message failed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have a pretty standard CodePipeline/CodeDeploy setup that has been working flawlessly for months. Suddenly, and without us changing anything, deployments fail with the following message:

> Validation of PKCS7 signed message failed

According to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-deployments.html#troubleshooting-deployments-agent-SHA-256), this should only happen on very old versions of the CodeDeploy agent:

> This error message indicates the instance is running a version of the CodeDeploy agent that supports only the SHA-1 hash algorithm. Support for the SHA-2 hash algorithm was introduced in version 1.0.1.854 of the CodeDeploy agent, released in November 2015. Effective October 17, 2016, deployments will fail if a version of the CodeDeploy agent earlier than 1.0.1.854 is installed.

However, that is not the case on my setup. All our instances run version 1.0-1.1597 (latest stable). I tried re-installing the agent, yet the issue remains. Deploying a different project with a very similar setup (same agent version) works without a hitch.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the CodeDeploy agent was stuck in limbo.

I did a fresh install, and after restarting the service a couple of times I managed to get the venerable `Loaded: loaded, Active: active (running)` status. Deployments now work fine.

That said, I have absolutely no idea what caused the issue. The agent was active when deployments were failing, and the error message is completely nonsensical.